# многомерный массив из php  в javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! На js из JSON восстановила объект такого вида:

```
{"1":{"108":{"3":"605500","6":"785000"},"113":{"6":"60000"}}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить в него новые значения?

Comment: Вот это: `"108":"3":"605500"` — некорректный JSON, если что.

Comment: ошиблась, исправила

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Всем спасибо, не знаю, правильно или нет сделала, но работает:
function save_prices_to_array(titles_of_prices_table_ID,ID_dv_k_p,ID_kompl_for_prices,elem)
{ 
 if (!(titles_of_prices_table_ID in js_conveniently_model_prices))
 {js_conveniently_model_prices[titles_of_prices_table_ID]=new Object();};
 if (!(ID_dv_k_p in js_conveniently_model_prices[titles_of_prices_table_ID]))
 {js_conveniently_model_prices[titles_of_prices_table_ID][ID_dv_k_p]=new Object();};
 js_conveniently_model_prices[titles_of_prices_table_ID][ID_dv_k_p][ID_kompl_for_prices]=elem.value;
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых, дать ему имя:

```
var sampleObj = {"1":{"108":"605500","6":"785000"},"113":{"6":"60000"}};
```

А потом - как угодно:

```
sampleObj['2'] = 3;
sampleObj.s = 15;
```

Comment: я так пробовала, в этом случае при попытке присвоить новое значение выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined

js_conveniently_model_prices[1][112][3]=5;

Comment: старые значения таким образом исправляются без проблем

Comment: @Mariya, при обращении к свойствам объекта необходимо писать так: `js_conveniently_model_prices['1']['112']['3']=5;`

Comment: ой, у меня так и есть, это сюда поторопилась набирать

Comment: Значит у вас нет свойства `js_conveniently_model_prices['1']['112']`

Comment: да, нет, я вот и не знаю, как правильнее сделать, мне надо заполнять только некоторые значения этого объекта, полученного из php-массива

Answer (score 0):

Перевести в объект json, добавить значения, перевести в строку.

Можно еще извратиться с парсингом, но есть вероятность все испортить.

Comment: нет, я именно в объект уже и не знаю как добавить значение

Comment: sampleObj["2"] = 3;
Как написано ниже. Только обязательно, обязательно кавычки и, внезапно, скобки, как у массива.

Comment: @knes, спасибо, поторопился и опечатался.